# Библиотека стилей для разметки(каркаса)

Tags: css, css3, bootstrap

А есть ли какая-то библиотека, в которой прописаны только стили для разметки? Например, в materialize или bootstrap используются стили для container, row, col s12, например. Но качать целый пакет стилей и использовать из него только разметку как-то не комильфо. В связи с этим, ищу библиотеку со стилями разметки(grid, как её называют в английском языке). Желательно, чистый css, не препроцессоры.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из того же самого bootstrap вы можете скачать только необходимые вам компоненты.
В частности **grid system**

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Есть еще достаточно интересная библиотека для построения **grid system** основанная на [flexbox](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjfluC8l8HPAhVDBywKHRscDX0QFggyMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffrontender.info%2Fa-guide-to-flexbox%2F&usg=AFQjCNH-LINIBfvM68WFgoOHuinmtFF0_g&bvm=bv.134495766,d.bGg)

http://flexboxgrid.com/

Comment: Спасибо, не знал на счёт компиляции bootstrap.